# What is the best way to organize a C++ game that involves a user choosing between paths in order to progress on a journey?

Tags: c++, structure

I am programming a simple C++ game that involves a user choosing a path in order to progress on a journey. For example:

> You have have reached a fork in the road. Do you:
>
> 1. Go right
> 2. Go left

The user can then input a number in order to choose which path to take. This program could get very complex and turn into spaghetti code and I am wonder what the best way to organize the code is.

Comment: Using functions? "Spaghetti code" refers to complex, convoluted, and *unreadable* code. It doesn't refer simply to any code with branches.

Comment: Structured programming? Be patient, use the source. Think.

Comment: I don't see why the question was voted down. The OP being inexperienced doesn't invalidate the question

Comment: @CodyGray Actually both of you are correct. The OP isn't saying his code would become spaghetti code due to branches, but due to an excessive use of unorganized branches which in turn would result in convoluted and unreadable code and therefore classifying as your definition of "spaghetti code"

Comment: Yes, I realize that. My point is that it might be premature to worry about writing spaghetti code. As long as you write something that is readable and understandable (and therefore maintainable), you're just fine. No need for excessive hand-wringing over design. I personally think that, for example, H_7's solution of putting things into an array and iterating over it with a `for` loop is *far* more confusing and difficult to maintain than a few clearly-delineated function calls.

Comment: What you are looking for may be an implementation of a tree.  If it is just left & right, look at binary tree.  Otherwise, look at generic tree.

Comment: @CodyGray Your right, I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your making a console application.

Due to the simplicity of your program it would probably be better to make your program procedural/structural rather than object oriented.

I would suggest breaking up your story into separate major parts, and then assign each part to a function. After completion, the function would call the function dealing with the next part in the story and so on till the end. Each function would pass in a value to the next function (i.e a string) signifying the user's decision to a certain point.

This allows better organization of the code, minimal complexity and does what it needs to do.

For example:

3 Little Pigs would be broken down into the functions string pigA(), string pigB, string pigC() and void resolution()

pigA() would pass in "death" to pigB() upon completion, and pigB() would pass in "death" to pigC(). pigC() however would pass in "lives" to resolution() (since the first two pigs die but the third lives) which would print "The End"

I realize this is a story and not a game, but a game can similaririly be broken down into smaller parts which are assigned to functions.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about two weeks ago and coded a very similar game in **C**, and after some if-else-if-else terrible spaghetti I ended up thinking in put the paths and choices each one in one different array, and then run a `for` loop for each interation, and checking in array, correct answer or not, left or right, and then extract the point on the other array to go, allowing the next "movement".

So u have `choices array`, and `paths array`, and the `for` loop realize all interations with minimal code. I hope I made myself clear, sorry about any english mistake. I don't know how this can be improved in **C++** but I guess this is a good starting point.